# How to reverse a string

Tags: java

I need to reverse the string of a user's input.

I need it done in the simplest of ways. I was trying to do reverseOrder(UserInput) but it wasn't working.

For example, user inputs abc I just take the string and print out cba

Comment: I realize you probably have a different problem to solve that might require reversing a string, but you need to know how to write this code.  In fact there's a non-zero chance it'll be asked in an interview.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString()
```

`java.util.Collections.reverseOrder` is for sorting in reverse of normal order.

Comment: Is it common practice here for the biggest point-earners to answer people's homework problems?

Comment: It's not immediately obvious that that is the easy way to reverse a string.

Comment: Wtf? This isn't homework... 

I'm assuming since it's so basic you assumed it was?

Comment: (As it happens, I think I found out the `StringBuffer.reverse` (no `StringBuilder` in those days) trick from Jon Skeet.)

Comment: @Jonathan: Nope. Homework would have go in the lines of `char [] chars = "ab".toCharArray(); for etc etc etc` Teachers *regularly* don't accept library calls solutions.

Comment: @Oscar @Phil.. Look at the Tags, this is homework. And there is no teacher here condoning a library call either.

Comment: @Nate: Phil is the topic starter. I feel we should give him the benefit of the doubt before condemning him.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer using Apache's [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) for this kind of thing. There are all kinds of goodies, including:

```
StringUtils.reverse("Hello World!");
```

yields: `!dlroW olleH`

```
StringUtils.reverseDelimited("Hello World!", ' ');
```

yields: `World! Hello`

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to programming, which I guess you are, my suggestion is "Why use simple stuff?". 
Understand the internals and play some!!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
String str = "abcasz";
char[] orgArr = str.toCharArray();
char[] revArr = new char[orgArr.length];
for (int i = 0; i < orgArr.length;i++)  {
revArr[i] = orgArr[orgArr.length - 1 - i];
}
String revStr = new String(revArr);
System.out.println(revStr);
```

Comment: Doesn't work for surrogate pairs... Getting used to using libraries is a jolly good idea.

Comment: @tom..I started with.."If you are new to programming..". The whole idea was to simulate learning :)

Answer (score 0):

There is an interesting method to do it so too.

```
   String input = "abc";
   //Here, input is String to reverse
   int b = input.length();
   String reverse = ""; // Declaring reverse String variable
     while(b!=0){
        //Loop for switching between the characters of the String input
        reverse += (input.charAt(b-1));
        b--;
        }
        System.out.println(reverse);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without going through the char sequence, easiest way:

```
public String reverse(String post) {       
    String backward = "";
    for(int i = post.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        backward = backward + post.substring(i, i + 1);
    }        
    return backward;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public String reverseString(final String input_String)
          {
              char temp;
              char[] chars = input_String.toCharArray();
              int N = chars.length;
              for (int i = 0 ; i < (N / 2) ; i++)
              {
                  temp = chars[i];
                  chars[i] = chars[N - 1 - i];
                  chars[N - 1 - i] = temp;
              }

              return new String(chars);
          }
```

Run :

```
    Pandora
    arodnaP
```

Comment: wtf? why are you doing this?