# how to reverse the output

Tags: java, loops, jcreator

```
Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
byte num, r, c;
System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
num = x.nextByte();
for (r = 1; r <= num; r++) {
    for (c = 1; c <= r; c++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Example output:

```
Enter a number: 4
*
**
***
****
```

How to change the output from:

```
*
**
***
****
```

to

```
****
***
**
*
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reverse a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598040/how-to-reverse-a-string)

Comment: Do it yourself, If It is your assignment.

Comment: @Surinderツ I think he did do it himself, and got the opposite output that he needed. That looks like he did most of the work to me.

Comment: hehe @Cruncher It is possible. :)

Comment: @kocko Not a dupe of that.

Answer (score 6):

It's just a case of reversing the logic in your loop.

```
for(r=num;r>=1;r--){
    for(c=1;c<=r;c++){
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
    }
}
```

And here's the evidence of it working: http://ideone.com/Kf8R4I

Answer (score 2):

```
 for(c = num - r; c >= 0; c--){
     System.out.print("*");
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change the outter for-loop,

From

```
 for(r=1;r<=num;r++){
```

To

```
 for(r=num;r>=1;r--){
```

An example output in console:

```
Enter a number: 4
****
***
**
*
```

Answer (score 0):

Build string with `StringBuilder` and use `reverse()` method