# Reversing a strings in an array of string[]

Tags: java, android

```
String[] imageSources;
```

I have some stings in imageSources, say *string1, string2* etc. in positions *imageSources[0],imageSources[1]* etc.

Is there any function(s) to reverse these strings?
I mean the string at last position should come to imageSource[0] and so on.

Comment: you can write your function to do that

Comment: But is there any built in functions to do that?

Comment: We aren't going to do your homework for you.

Comment: @gabe Just want to know the answer, if you are not willing just leave it.

Comment: No.  The point of this site is to help people who need advice and cannot solve the problem on their own.  It is not here to help lazy people pass a comp sci 101 assignment.  These types of questions are not welcome here.

Comment: @user3407787: I have an answer for you: http://www.google.com

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reverse a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598040/how-to-reverse-a-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But is there any built in functions to do that?

There is.

But before I give you the answer, I just want to point out that it should be a trivial matter to write code to reverse an array for yourself.

If it is not trivial for you, then you obviously *need more practice* ... and that means writing the code yourself.

---

OK.  Here is the answer:

```
String[] strings = ...
Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(strings));
```

Now if you are a good student, you will now lookup the javadocs, read them carefully, and work out what that code is doing and why it works.

Answer (score 0):

THIS WORKS!! I'VE CHECKED IT!!

```
    String[] imagesources = {"item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5"};
    String[] images = new String[imagesources.length];

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+imagesources[0] + "\n"+imagesources[1] + "\n"+imagesources[2] + "\n"+imagesources[3] + "\n"+imagesources[4], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    for (int i=0; i<imagesources.length; i++) {
        images[i] = imagesources[4-i];
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+images[0] + "\n"+images[1] + "\n"+images[2] + "\n"+images[3] + "\n"+images[4], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Collections.reverse( Arrays.asList(imagesources));
```

Comment: Don't give them answers when they come here with comp sci 101 questions and no attempt to solve it on their own.  It just makes them bad students, then they graduate and become bad coworkers.

Comment: @GabeSechan agree dude...

Comment: @GabeSechan indeed..but ans is valid.You can vote to close the question instead..

Comment: @GabeSechan how bad you are, why are you like this?

Comment: This doesn't compile.

Comment: Yes.  Collections.reverse does an in-place reversal of its argument.  It is a `void` method.  The code is NOT valid.

Comment: @StephenC yeah..that was really dumb :)..Corrected.. Thanks Radiodef